# What does size() mean in a 2D vector of std::vector<vector<double>>?

Tags: c++, vector

If I have a 2D vector represented like this:

```
#include <vector>

typedef vector<vector<double>> Matrix;

Matrix A = {
  {  0,   2,  0, -2, 2.5},
  {  2,   0,  1,  0, 1.6},
  {  0,   1,  0,  1,   0},
  { -2,   0,  1,  0,   0},
  {2.5, 1.6,  0,  0,   0}
};
```

If `A.size()` returns the rows, does it count each sub-vector as 1 row? Why does `A[0].size()` mean the number of columns?

Comment: what is the matrix library you are using?  Eigen?

Comment: C++ does not have built-in `Matrix`  type. Meaning that matrix is provided by library. Which library are you using?

Comment: Sorry, how would I find the library I use on ubuntu linux on sublime text 3?

Comment: @Aorus The question is where the `Matrix` type comes from - for instance if it is a typedef for `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` or something else. (It's a bit unclear what you dont' understand - `A.size()` is the number of elements in `A`, `A[0].size()` is the number of elements in `A[0]`.)

Comment: Oh right, its a vector in vector. 
typedef vector<vector<double>> Matrix;
I don't understand how A[0].size() is for number of columns.

Comment: @Aorus Each row has the same number of  elements. That number is the number of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ doesn't have a `std::matrix` but it does support multi-dimensional arrays as well as vectors inside of vectors.

For example `std::vector<std::vector>>` can act as a double matrix, but care must be taken to properly access the underlying variables. In essense, this doubly-layered `vector` is merely a vector inside of a vector; therefore, doing a dobule `[x][y]` will not work without some special overloading of `operator[]`.

**For a vector inside of a vector, `A.size()` will return the amount of elements in the 1st dimension, and `A[0].size()` will return the amount of elements in the vector at the 0th index in the 1st dimension.** Note that it is not required for each vector inside of the 1st-dimensional vector to be of uniform length.

It's possible to create a scalable X-dimensional matrix, but it's a bit messy and may be beyond the scope of this question.

Here is a basic example of how to create a "2d vector" within C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        matrix.push_back(std::vector<int>());

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
            matrix[i].push_back(i*10 + j);   
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
            std::cout << matrix[i].at(j) << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Coliru for 3d-matrix: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b949266621fb45fb

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what library you use. If you use Boost uBLAS, you can refer to a documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/container_concept.htm#2Matrix). If not, there are many other matrix libraries you can use. You can check out [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/351/recommendations-for-a-usable-fast-c-matrix-library) for more detail of each library.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know how the Matrix initialized.
Let's insert the float numbers into the Matrix as below.

```
Matrix A;
vector<double> a1, a2, a3, a4;
a1.push_back(0);
a1.push_back(2);
a1.push_back(0);
a1.push_back(-2);
a1.push_back(2.5);

a2.push_back(2);
a2.push_back(0);
a2.push_back(1);
a2.push_back(0);
a2.push_back(1.6);

a3.push_back(-2);
a3.push_back(0);
a3.push_back(1);
a3.push_back(0);
a3.push_back(0);

a4.push_back(2.5);
a4.push_back(1.6);
a4.push_back(0);
a4.push_back(0);
a4.push_back(0);

A.push_back(a1);
A.push_back(a2);
A.push_back(a3);
A.push_back(a4);
```

Now, 4 vectors(a1, a2, a3, a4) have been inserted into the Matrix. So the A.size() is 4.
And a1.size() is 5. A[0] is a1, so A[0].size() is 5.